# What are good adjectives that mean “not yet connected”?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm working on a browser-based tool that allows users to interact with other users they are matched with. Relationships between users progress in a linear fashion along a series of states, initiated when a user requests to be connected with another user.

In the interface of the tool, a user can view all of the users they're matched with, regardless of the state of their relationship.

I'd like to allow users to navigate to a filtered version of this view that shows only users they have not yet requested a connection with, but I'm having trouble with what to call it.

"Unconnected Matches" isn't quite right. "Unconnected" carries unwanted connotations of having once been connected in the past.

Ideally the phrase would follow the pattern: *adjective* + "matches".

This phrase would only live in a tab in the interface and not in a sentence anywhere, but if it helps with context, here's another way to think about it:

> This is a list of your _______ matches. You can request to be connected with any of them.

Any good alternatives? I was pointed this direction from ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How about ***potential*** matches?  Or ***prospective*** matches?

Comment: @PellMel They've already been matched at this point, so "potential" and "prospective" don't feel appropriate. In truth, they are matches that are potential connections—but I want to find a way to convey that without using the word "connection".

Comment: ***Pending*** might work here as well.

Comment: @JimMack Again, they've already been matched, so "pending matches" isn't appropriate.

Comment: I'd drop the adjective entirely and give the connected state it's own unique term like "connections". Solves abiguity issues all over.

Comment: @TheNate As stated in the title of the question, the goal is to find a way to describe the state of being not yet connected, so "connections" doesn't help.

Comment: I suggested using connection exclusively for those that are connected and a *completely different term* for any potential or pending states. (possibly one of those) It's not an answer to your question as asked, but it would solve your problem as described.

Comment: De nada. (I put it as a comment because it is more a UIX than English approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *[candidate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/candidate)*

> A person or thing regarded as suitable for or likely to receive a particular fate, treatment, or position

*Oxford Dictionary Online*

(The downside is possible association with politicos we may not like during this election season)

Comment: That's interesting. It captures the essence of what I want to communicate, but I think it will seem out of place to users in this context. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try tribe or tribesmen. It expresses that they are connected in some way but it doesn't necessarily imply ever having an established relationship

Answer (score 0):

Try "unconfirmed" matches. This tells them the match is already suggested by the system but not confirmed by the user (by explicitly requesting a connection).

Answer (score 0):

How about *latent* matches? This seems to fit your specification: the matches exist but are not yet activated.

One definition of *Latent* is "*present, but not yet active, developed, or obvious*" [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/latent).