# What single word (up to three if necessary) could be used in place of "I could not have said it better myself?"

Tags: synonyms

I'm a voracious reader.  I collect a multitude of quotes and article snippets.  My reason for doing this is that I frequently find an idea expressed by an author that is precisely what I've had in my mind, but could never put into words.  I collect these quotes to have my own library for future reference in my own conversations and writing.

What single word (up to three if necessary) could be used in place of "I could not have said it better myself?"

Example sentence:

When I read the article, the author expressed my thoughts so perfectly, I thought ______.

Comment: For some reason my clarification comment is not present. 
 I found this question to follow for acceptable format:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431336/what-single-word-could-be-used-in-place-of-long-drawn-out-procedure?rq=1

Comment: I'm new to all this so forgive me for asking or placing a comment here that doesn't belong.  Whoever entered the example sentence (in my explanation)  is a mind-reader!  Thank you.

Comment: I sense self-referentiality.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the comment.  Should I delete all of my comments?  Actually should I delete this question?  It seems the hold has not been lifted even though I followed the exact language from other similar "single word that means a phrase" questions.  I'll wait another day or two and delete the whole thing.  Complete waste of time for the group and for a newbie if no guidance given to improve and create acceptable question.

Comment: I was wondering whether my comment would be understood as the light-hearted observation that it was meant to be, or whether I needed to include a `:-)` smiley face.  I was noting that your question asked for a way of saying “I could not have said it better myself”, and then, when jimm101 wrote a sample sentence, you said, essentially, «I could not have said it better myself».  So, while referring to an example sentence, you gave an example sentence (except “you are a mind-reader!” is too many words). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Sadly, it appears that [the “hold” is not likely to be lifted](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/276738).  But I see no reason to delete anything (except possibly for [the second comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/432787/26083#comment1039256_432787) — the one talking about folders and bookmarks — because it’s not entirely clear how it relates to the question).  If it is meant to clarify of illuminate the question, you should [edit] it into the question. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Additionally, new users are advised not to delete too many questions, and the system might not allow you to delete this one, because it has two answers, one of which is up voted.  But, if you want to delete your comments and try to delete the question, that’s your decision to make.

Comment: Thanks Scott!  Well said, or should I say well put?  I deleted the bookmark comment and have decided to leave everything else alone for posterity.  For the record, I would vote for the "Well Said" answer below as the correct answer.  Not that it matters as I'm just a plebe here, but I followed a "non-hold" question format almost to the letter for my "edit".  I do understand the "opinion" designation, and reluctantly agree, but don't understand how almost identical questions aren't marked as opinion as well.  As examples:

Comment: (Cont'd) ...  As examples:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431336/what-single-word-could-be-used-in-place-of-long-drawn-out-procedure?rq=1 
 and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326948/what-are-good-adjectives-that-mean-not-yet-connected?rq=1

Comment: (1) FWIW, I do not understand or agree with the closure of your question.  I’ve been on this site > 5 years, accruing > 5K rep, and I still don’t understand everything that happens here.  I believe that a lot of it is arbitrary: the rules are subjective and the decisions seem capricious.  (2) May I suggest that, if you have a question like this in the future, you (2a) use the [phrase-request] and/or [single-word-requests] tags(s) instead of [synonyms],  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2b) to the extent that this applies, specify what part of speech (e.g., noun or adjective) you are looking for, and (2c) provide a sample sentence demonstrating how the word or phrase would be used.  (3) I agree that the “Well said” answer is the better of the ones that got posted before the question was closed (note that he also suggested “You read my mind!” before you used “you are a mind-reader!”).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You can’t *vote* for it yet (you don’t have enough reputation to have that privilege), but I believe that you can “accept” it (the fact that the question is closed shouldn’t be an issue). To the left of the answer, below the voting buttons and the vote score, you should see a gray checkmark.  If you click on it, it will turn green. This (a) marks it as your choice as the best answer, (b) gives the author of the answer 15 rep points, and (c) gives you 2 rep points.

Answer (score 1):

- Well said!
- My thought exactly!
- You read my mind!
- Ditto!

These are a few common expressions that came to mind.

Comment: I'm waiting until the "put on hold as primarily opinion-based" is removed, but I think "Well said!" is pretty close.  I was hoping that a word like "precis" would exist for my sentence, but probably not.

Comment: Same! (This is what my teen says a lot.)

Answer (score -1):

**likewise**  [Mer-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likewise)

“I'm pleased to meet you.” “Likewise.” [=I'm also pleased to meet you] [in a sentence][2](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/likewise)

Comment: (1) Good for you, for linking to a dictionary definition.  But, in addition to linking to it, you should *also* quote the relevant part(s).  (2) “Likewise” means that ***B*** is similar to ***A**,* and, in the example you cited, can even be used as a shorthand for saying “Likewise, *B.*”  It *doesn’t* really mean, “Wow! I was thinking something along the lines of ***A**,* but you phrased it much better than I would have been able to.”